# Operator overloading without explicit type casting

Tags: c++, string, class, operator-keyword

I try to make my own small String Class for practice purposes. I want to overload the const wchar_t* operator to return the buffer saved within the String object but it fails, when I actually access the object. It's conversion operator isn't called. It only works, when I explicitly type cast the object via `(const wchar_t*) mystring`

*EDIT:*

```
// CString.h
class CString {
private:
    wchar_t* _string;

    void set(const wchar_t text[]);

public:
    CString();
    CString(const wchar_t text[]);
    CString(const CString& text);

    ~CString();

    operator const wchar_t*() const;
};

// CString.cpp
#include "CString.h"

CString::CString() { set(L""); }
CString::CString(const wchar_t text[]) { set(text); }
CString::~CString() { delete[] _string; }

void CString::set(const wchar_t text[]) {
    delete[] _string;

    _string = new wchar_t[wcslen(text)];
    wcscpy(_string, text);
}

CString::operator const wchar_t*() const {
    return _string;
}

// main.cpp
int main() {
    CString* helloWorld = new CString(L"Test 123");

    MessageBox(NULL, helloWorld, L"", MB_OK);       // This doesn't work
    MessageBox(NULL, (const wchar_t*) helloWorld, L"", MB_OK);  // This works, but I don't explicitly want to use the cast everytime.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You may want to include the relevant operator overload code from your string class, and an example of how you're trying to use it, as well as the behavior you're seeing.  Otherwise it will be very difficult to answer your question; this usually results in the question being closed.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but you are expecting your operator which is for the object itself to work for pointer to the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you are working in windows, `CString` is a class from the ATL/MFC.  Reusing the same name for a class of your own is rude.

If you aren't, you should provide a signature for `MessageBox`.

I'll assume you are working in Windows world.

Your problem is that a `CString*` is not the same thing as a `CString`.  You defined an operator to turn a `CString` into a `wchar_t const*`.  Not surprisingly, this doesn't work for a `CString*`.

Change the definition of `helloWorld` to `CString helloWorld = CString(L"Test 123");`  -- no `new`, no pointers -- and your code works.

As yet another aside, the explicit cast you did results in undefined behavior, as it reinterprets a pointer to an object as a pointer to a buffer of characters.  This is one of the many, many reasons why using C-style casts is a bad idea, because the difference between a reinterpret cast and a static cast requires a lot of context.  To see an error, change your MessageBox call to `MessageBox( NULL, static_cast<const wchar_t*>(helloWorld), L"", MB_OK);`  Did the code with the explicit cast ever run and print anything sensible?

If you really must put `helloWorld` in the free store, dereference it when you are using it (in both the implicit, and explicit cast cases).  Ie, replace uses of `helloWorld` with `*helloWorld`.  I would advise against it -- there is no good reason to store this particular instance on the free store.